# problem with axis2 libarary

Tags: android, apache-axis

I wanted to convert a wsdl file into java. I installed Axis2 plugin into Eclipse so that I can use wsdl2java. I successfully converted the wsdl files into java but there are certain things that are not getting support now and are causing errors. I think I am not correctly integrated the libraries of axis.. for example

```
org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils.BeanUtil.getUniquePrefix(); is causing error (this can't be resolved to a type)
javax.xml.namespace (can't be resolved into a type)    
org.apache.axis2 (I think I am not correctly importing these libraries)
```

Can someone help me here.. I downloaded org.apache.axis2.eclipse.codegen.plugin_1.6.0.jar file (according to the instructions) at eclipse/dropins directory.. Can someone help me how can I give support for libraries of axis or how can I include the libraries with my current ANDROID PROJECT.. 
many thanks

Comment: Hi, how save you installed the plugin because i have a problem with this. Which wersion of eclipse have you and which wersion of axis2 ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javax is not part of Android, you have to import all Axis2 libraries in order to make it available for Android.